# How to detect when asynchronously loaded jquery has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, asynchronous, load

I want to load jquery asynchronously on a page and then load an other script which depends on jquery (it executes jquery code when loaded). But how can I detect if jquery has finished lodading. Is there an event for this in jquery which fires when the library finished loading?

In theory I could load jquery like this:

```
<script async src="jquery.js" onload="jqueryloaded()"></script>
```

but I want the code to work on older browsers too which may not support the async and onload attributes. (In this case jquery is loaded synchronously.) That's why I'm looking for an event which jquery emits when it's loaded. Is there one?

Comment: I'm not understanding. For browsers that load it synchronously, it'll be done loading after the tag, so you could just put another script below it, and have it check to see if `window.jQuery` is present. `<script>if (window.jQuery) jqueryloaded();</script>` Otherwise, don't use `<script async` if you need to support all browsers.

Comment: @cookiemonster your comment would made a good answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load javascript async, then check DOM loaded before executing callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249030/load-javascript-async-then-check-dom-loaded-before-executing-callback)

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks, but I think Paul's answer below should be used over hacks to accommodate `<script async` functionality. I just wasn't sure exactly what Tom was getting at.

Comment: @ cookie monster   the question was about a single solution which works both for async/sync situation without handling them differently

Comment: @Tom: Isn't your `onload` handler a single solution that works for both async/sync situations? The event should fire either way, right?

Comment: @cookie monster it may be if older browser all support onload. Do they? They may be, but if so then why is it not the highest rated answer? It's possible that my assumption that onload may not work on older browsers was false. In this case you answer is the solution.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, `onload` has been around for ages. Highest rated answer where?

Comment: @cookie monster Here. :) Nobody posted this answer to my question  that onload works either case, so I should not worry about it, and simply use `<script async ...`

Comment: @Tom: It would seem that way. I'm doing some quick checking for old IE bugs. Maybe there were issues I didn't know about.

Comment: @Tom: I think you may be right. Seems like there are some old IE issues with `script.onload` support.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'jquery.js';
script.onload = jqueryloaded; // thx @Cookie_Monster
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: +1 though you can do `script.onload = jqueryloaded;` to make it a little shorter.

Comment: @JFit `$.ajax` is a jQuery function, and this topic is discussing loading jQuery, so no - you can't.  You could use AJAX though.  I think this is the best answer though as you can get it to load after the DOM (put the script at the bottom of the body) so that it doesn't slow down the page load, then who cares if it's asynchronous or not?

Comment: @JFit `$.ajax()` is a jQuery method, you can't use it before jQuery has been loaded. That's said, for other scripts, you could use: `$.getScript();` method

Comment: @A.Wolff: This should load it asynchronously. No?

Comment: @cookiemonster No, why it shoudl? To get it async, you will need: `script.async = true;` But i'll go to test it

Comment: @cookie: yes... i'm 99% sure

Comment: @A.Wolff: Pretty sure appended `script` elements are always loaded async. That's why people use `document.write` when they want synchronous script loading as the page loads. *EDIT: Here's a demo:* http://jsfiddle.net/x3J5H/

Comment: Ah, the good old `document.createElement('script')` method. I was hoping jquery has an event for that, so the simple `<script async` technique can be used. I don't really get why jquery does not have such an event (e.g. libraryloaded). It would be much simpler.

Comment: @Tom: If there was a jQuery specific event that fired when jQuery  finished loading, you wouldn't be able to bind the handler unless jQuery was already loaded.

Comment: @Tom isn't it what already do the onload event on script tag?

Comment: It would be nice to be able to specify a callback function in the jQuery url.

Comment: @Archer maybe a little off topic but: http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes!! That has bugged me since the very first time I added a script include to a page.  Also, if I can't put anything inside the script tags (when it's an include), why the hell can it not be a self closing tag???

Comment: @A. Wolff if onload works that answers my quesion. I assumed when asking the question that some older browsers might not support the onload attribute. It may have been a false assumption.

Comment: The line `script.onload = jqueryloaded;` should be `script.onload = jqueryloaded();`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://headjs.com/?.
An example it's:

```
head.load("jQuery.js", function() {
 // Call a function when done
 console.log("Done loading jQuery");
});
```